# Custom JS for youtube videos, need sound to work with autoplay

Tags: javascript, youtube

I have a custom JS script that forces YouTube videos to autoplay, and it has worked perfectly for a long time:

```
const youtubeUrlPattern = /^((?:https?:)?\/\/)?((?:www|m)\.)?((?:youtube\.com|youtu.be))(\/(?:[\w\-]+\?v=|embed\/|v\/)?)([\w\-]+)(\S+)?$/;

[...document.querySelectorAll('iframe')].filter((iframeEl) => {
// Filter to iframes loading YouTube URLs only.
return iframeEl.src.match(youtubeUrlPattern);
}).forEach((iframeEl) => {
const a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = iframeEl.src;
a.search = a.search || '?';
a.search += '&autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0&mute=1';
iframeEl.src = a.href;
});
```

The problem now is I need sound but still need it to autoplay. These screens are made by multiple people embedding YT videos and no matter what they do when copying embed code, I need this script to force every video to autoplay, loop and have sound. Changing mute to 0 in that script enforces the sound (the speaker is no longer crossed out on page load) but the video won't autoplay.

What can I do here to force both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
'&autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0&mute=1'
```

needs to be replaced with

```
'&autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0'
```

Mute needs to be removed.

Comment: AAAAH that worked! Thank you, I had originally removed mute but I had another line trying to allow autoplay that broke it. Seems like this was the answer all along! Thank you